# How to set restraints to the outer-edges of variable typefaces?

Tags: html, css, typography

I am creating my first variable logo for a client using HTMl & CSS. I have created the effect I want, first letter expanding as the second contracts but; the outer edges of my characters are also moving inwards and outwards slightly. What have I done wrong to cause this to happen or what can I add to lock the points of the outer edges to stop this from happening?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/finlaymilne/pen/ydqKRp)

```
.em-tight { letter-spacing: -1.5em; }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'etc-trispace';
  src: url(data:font/woff2;base64,d09...) format('woff2-variations');
}

body {
font-family: 'etc-trispace';
text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
margin: 10vh auto;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes bigger {
0%   {font-variation-settings: "wght" 200, "wdth" 50 ; }
25%   {font-variation-settings: "wght" 200, "wdth" 200; }
50%   {font-variation-settings: "wght" 200, "wdth" 200; }
75%   {font-variation-settings: "wght" 200, "wdth" 50;  }
100% {font-variation-settings: "wght" 200, "wdth" 50 ;}
    }

p span {
    animation: bigger infinite;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    font-size: 40vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: normal;
    }

p span:nth-child(2) {
animation-delay: 2.5s
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite an impressive animation.

Here are my thoughts.

Sometimes I use a guide to see what's truly going on under the hood. Try adding these CSS borders for troubleshooting:

```
p span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  border:thin dashed red;
}
p span:nth-child(1) {
  border:thin dashed green;
}
```

Then, try the animation with equal characters in each `span`. Use a character such as `H` or `M` that have a different geometry to give you more information:

```
<p class="em-tight"><span>O</span><span>O</span></p>
```

This should allow you to see that there is a space before and after the glyph which is also expanding and contracting with the animation.

In typography, this space is called the "side-bearing". This space is a non-editable component of the glyph. Furthermore, the glyph may have a different side-bearing on the leading edge (left) of the glyph as it does on the trailing edge (right).

Our guide borders show us that the side-bearing in your animation is also expanding and contracting with the letterform, and that the left/right bearing is unequal. Hence, the non-uniform nature of your spacing.

In CSS, we have a few tools for manually spacing (kerning) the individual letters, such as the `letter-spacing` property. I believe the problem you are encountering is that such a `letter-spacing` is not yet integrated with the `font-variation-settings` that you are using in your animation.

Workarounds:

1.
You can convert these glyphs to outline images and delete the side-bearing. You can then replace it with spacing that you can control. This will work if you have no real requirement to actually use type in the animation. If the animation is a logo, as you say above, then there is no significant meaning that `D` and `H` can impart to either a search engine or a browser in the form that you present it in. Given the information provided, this would be my first go-to solution. A primitive animated GIF would do this job in a trice.

2.
Switch to a different typeface, which has a uniform side-bearing. This may not be possible if you are – as I suspect – using brand-specific typefaces and are forced to use a specific typeface.

3.
If you have access to resources, you can have the type re-cut — for at least the two characters that you require. These resources might be your own knowledge of type editing software, or a budget for hiring a type designer. The type licence must be considered as well.